# unable to bind value to radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a radio group in a list of items. I am unable to set the radion button checked based on the value. Please guide me.

HTML

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
  <nb-radio-group class="p-3 d-inline-flex">
                            <nb-radio [checked]="item.data.v === true">open</nb-radio>
                            <nb-radio [checked]="item.data.v === false">close</nb-radio>
                          </nb-radio-group>
  </div>
```

only the radio button in last item of an array shows wether the radio button is checked or not. others does not bind data properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the value property

```
<nb-radio-group class="p-3 d-inline-flex" [(value)]="item.data.v">
  <nb-radio [value]="true">open</nb-radio>
  <nb-radio [value]="false">close</nb-radio>
</nb-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a *ngswitch to display your opion then based on if the user click or not you will bind data see this example using checkbox and also item.data,v should be a boolean

```
enter code here
<td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.done" /></td>
<td [ngSwitch]="item.done">
<span *ngSwitchCase="true">
      Yes
</span>
<span *ngSwitchDefault>
      No
</span>
</td>
```

and also u should use a filter to return data based on true or false